# Deleting one object from CartItems in razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, cart, shopping-cart

i have some products in my Cart via cookies, now i want to select and delete them from cart,

```
public class CartModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<CartItem> CartItems;
        public const string CookieName = "cart-items";

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var value = Request.Cookies[CookieName];
            CartItems = serializer.Deserialize<List<CartItem>>(value); //error accurred in this line
            foreach (var item in CartItems)
                item.TotalItemPrice = item.UnitPrice * item.Count;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetRemoveFromCart(long id)
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var value = Request.Cookies[CookieName];
            Response.Cookies.Delete(CookieName);
            var cartItems = serializer.Deserialize<List<CartItem>>(value);
            var itemToRemove = cartItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            cartItems.Remove(itemToRemove);
            var options = new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) };
            Response.Cookies.Append(CookieName, serializer.Serialize(cartItems), options);
            return RedirectToPage("/Cart");
        }
```

until i don't click on the delete button, everything is ok, i don't have any error in OnGet on Cart Razor page. but when i click on the delete button and OnGetRemoveFromCart's handler is executed,CartItems is null on OnGet!
the errorr: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.CartItems was null.'

Answer (score 0):

> `Response.Cookies.Delete(CookieName);`

You delete the cookie in the `OnGetRemoveFromCart` handler, so `value` becomes null in the `OnGet` handler. You should always check for `null` before accessing cookie values:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var value = Request.Cookies[CookieName];
    if(value is not null)
    {
        CartItems = serializer.Deserialize<List<CartItem>>(value); 
        foreach (var item in CartItems)
        {
            item.TotalItemPrice = item.UnitPrice * item.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but for example i have two product, i delete just one of them, but both of them have deleted,

Comment: Response.Cookies.Append(CookieName, serializer.Serialize(cartItems), options);   maybe this line dosn,t work corectly, because after deleting in OnGet method, value becomes null

Comment: If you delete a cookie, its entire contents are deleted. If you want to remove one item form the cart, update hthe content of the cookie.